# Why is Stripe API integration suddenly generating cannot convert Symbol into Integer errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm having some trouble retrieving data from Stripe into my rails app. It's strange, because it just started breaking this weekend, and I don't know why. Rolling back code to a previous commit, at which point I know for certain the pages this code was one worked, did not work. At that previous commit, the code is still broken. Furthermore, I haven't changed the code. I'm trying to figure out what is wrong.
 I've isolated which line of code the problem is on, but I'm not sure what is going on.

Previously, in the view, we had the following code. This code worked, until this weekend.

```
<%= @stripe_details[:active_card][:type] %>, ending in <%= @stripe_details[:active_card][:last4] %><br/>
```

This was supported by the following code in the controller:

```
if current_user.stripe_id
  @stripe_details = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id).to_hash
end
```

Having combed through the Stripe API documentation, it seemed like the problem was that Stripe doesn't return an active_card. It does return a default_card. However, when I switched the code to the following:

```
<%= @stripe_details[:default_card][:type] %>, ending in <%= @stripe_details[:default_card][:last4] %><br/>
```

I got an error on it: cannot convert Symbol into Integer.

I have no idea what is going on, because, as I said, the version at the top of the post worked with no problems until suddenly it didn't. Possibly worth mentioning was that what seemed to potentially be a trigger event for that was that I accidentally pushed and deployed code with the test API keys instead of the live keys, and the user's account was created with live keys. However, I caught this, and changed the codes to the proper live keys, and this problem started occuring. (When the wrong keys were being used, I was getting an error about the customer not existing in the test version of the Stripe database.)

I'm just baffled as to a) how our code worked when we were calling the wrong thing from the API (I inherited this code) and b) why it stopped working and how to get it working again.
What is broken? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stripe API Upgrades page](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2013-07-05) list the following recent update, which sounds like it has something to do with what you are seeing:

> **2013-07-05**
>   Customer objects now include a cards sublist and a default_card id in place of a fully expanded active_card. The default_card attribute can be expanded into a card object when retrieving the customer but is not expanded by default.

Stripe customer objects now return a list of cards and another default_card attribute which, from what I can tell, is the ID of the default card which can then be found on the cards list.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why it happened suddenly, AND why I'm getting the can't convert Symbol into Integer problem. I'm not getting expanded card. I saw that when I went to upgrade, but didn't think it would affect our code (which I hadn't written.) Well, someday, when I've made enough mistakes like that, learning from them will be what will make me not a newbie at this.